# Random access contents of Jekyll collection

Tags: jekyll

I'm using a Jekyll collection to generate a reveal.js presentation. Each file in the collection represents one slide and are named sequentially, eg 01.md, 02.md, etc. This all works fine but I want to find a more flexible method to order slides.

If I can randomly access the files in the collection, rather than sequentially iterate through them, I could maintain the order of slides external to the collection - something like: [0,1,3,2,4].

Where the collection is defined as:

```
collections:
  reality:
    title: Reality Slide Deck
    output: false
```

I can get the content of item 3 of the collection with:

```
{{site.reality[3].content}}
```

How do I access the front matter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any front matter's variable is available under is own name.

```
{{site.reality[3].title}}
```

or

```
{{site.reality[3].variableName}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the content of your site using site.collection as is explained in the documentation at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#documents

To access only one collection you can use a conditional statement.

```
{% for info in site.collections %}
<ul>
    <li>{{ info }}</li>
    <li>The name of the collection: {{ info.label }}</li>
    {% for stuff in info.docs %}
    <li>{{ stuff.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

After saying all of this you can of course just loop through the one collection as below:

```
{% for real in site.reality %}
    <li>{{ real.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The only other method that may work it to create an array using liquid syntax

```
{{ "a~b" | split:"~" }} #=> ['a','b']
```

Not sure if this answers your question, I hope it's useful for someone.